# Sonar integration with Ant

Tags: ant, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am try to integrate the sonar with ant. My SonarQube server is running fine but when i am building the XML using ant i  am getting the following error.

```
Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
[sonar:sonar] Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
[sonar:sonar] Property 'sonar.jdbc.password' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
[sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\Users\XYZ\.sonar\cache
[sonar:sonar] Load plugins index
[sonar:sonar] Load plugins index (done) | time=26ms
[sonar:sonar] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
[sonar:sonar] Process project properties

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\XYZ\git\ABCAPI\ant\build.xml:264: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock
```

I am new to sonar. I also added the the sonar.properties file and tried, but then also I am getting the error Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock.

I have tried placing the jdbc properties to build xml directly also but no gain.

I have seen previously discussion but they were of no help.